# SoapClient Php Trouble sending xml data

Tags: php, simplexml, soap-client

I am using a web service to grab user data in XML and then resend it to a second web service with changes. The problem is everytime I send the request I end up making a new user with no data. This means that the first 3 elements are being accepted but the User object is not being accepted. I have tried to use both xml and an aarray as the input but nothing works. The SaveUser service requires a complex object and its WSDL requirements look like

```
<s:element name="SaveUser">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CompanyID" type="s:long"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="tns:User"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Here is the xml I want to send and is represented by $userDataXML in php code

```
<User>
<AccountExpiryDate>2114-08-11T15:22:08.983</AccountExpiryDate>
<AccountFailedLoginAttempts>0</AccountFailedLoginAttempts>
<AccountLastActiveDate>2015-12-11T13:17:57.6916477-05:00</AccountLastActiveDate>
<AccountLastIPAddress>192.81.170.5</AccountLastIPAddress>
<AccountLastLoginDate>2015-12-11T13:17:57.6916477-05:00</AccountLastLoginDate>
<AccountLoggedIn>true</AccountLoggedIn>
<AccountLogin>testuser3</AccountLogin>
<AccountPassword>password</AccountPassword>
<AccountPasswordChangeRequired>false</AccountPasswordChangeRequired>
<Active>true</Active>
<Address>
<CompanyID>0</CompanyID>
<ID>0</ID>
<UserID>210</UserID>
</Address>
<AddressList>
<Address>
<CompanyID>0</CompanyID>
<ID>0</ID>
<UserID>210</UserID>
</Address>
</AddressList>
<CreatedByUserID>1</CreatedByUserID>
<CreatedDate>2015-10-29T19:23:29.64</CreatedDate>
<CompanyID>4</CompanyID>
<Email1>fasd@THIS.HAS</Email1>
<ID>210</ID>
<LanguageID>0</LanguageID>
<ModifiedByUserID>1</ModifiedByUserID>
<ModifiedDate>2015-10-29T19:26:08.59</ModifiedDate>
<RoleID>9</RoleID>
<StoreID>0</StoreID>
<TokenID/>
<UpdateTimestamp>
<DateTime>2015-11-17T19:45:46</DateTime>
<MilliSeconds>718</MilliSeconds>
</UpdateTimestamp>
<Verified>true</Verified>
<XMLData>
<data xmlns=""/>
</XMLData>
</User>
```

and here is my php code for the SaveUser part

```
$clientSaveUser = new SoapClient('$WSDL',array('trace'=>1));
    $saveUserQueryData = array(     
                        "Username"=> $master,
                        "Password"=>$masterPass,
                        "CompanyID"=>$compid,
                        "User"=>$userDataXML
                        );
    $saveUser = $clientSaveUser->SaveUser($saveUserQueryData);

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $lastResponseSaveUser = $clientSaveUser->__getLastResponse();
```

Thanks for any help!